# Babel doesn't ingore files outside the directory

Tags: babeljs

Here is my directory structure:

```
root/
└── nodejs_project/
    ├── node_modules/
    ├── src/
    ├── babel.config.json
    ├── package.json
    └── package-lock.json
└── another_project/
    └── folder1/
        └── static/
    └── folder2/
        └── static/
```

Here is my babel.config.json

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/react", "minify"],
    "ignore": ["**/*.min.js"]
}
```

Ignoring works well when `.js` files are in `src/` directory:

```
...\root\nodejs_project>npx babel src/ --out-dir src/ --out-file-extension .min.js
```

But `ignore` rule stops working when `.js` files are in `another_project/` directory:

```
...\root\nodejs_project>npx babel ../another_project/ --out-dir ../another_project/ --out-file-extension .min.js
```

How can I set `babel.config.json` to ignore all of the `*.min.js` files in `another_project/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me in any directories:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/react", "minify"],
    "ignore": ["../**/*.min.js"]
}
```